# $ f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $f(x+y)= f(x) f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $ f(x+y)= f(x) f(y) ,\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=1+x g(x); $ where $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)=1.$ Then the function $ f(x) $ is which of the following?
>
> 1. $e^x$
> 2. $2^x$
> 3. A non-constant polynomial
> 4. equal to $1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb R$.

**EDIT:** My Attempt:  We see that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=1 $ (By Calculating and putting the value of $f(x)$) and that means $f'(0)=1.$ Also putting $y=0$ in the relation $ f(x+y)= f(x) f(y) ,\forall x,y \in \mathbb R$,I get $f(0)=1.$ So,I can eliminate options $2$ and $4.$ Am I going in the right direction?

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There are a few ways to approach this problem. One is to start at the beginning and decide what it must be. The other is to try the four solutions out and see which one sticks to the paper.

Comment: Try to work out the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @mixedmath I want the first "start at the beginning and decide what it must be."

Comment: What is $f(0)$? How could you say it is not zero?

Comment: It has to be the first option. I have seen a similar problem. But in that the $ g(x) $ part was not there. So I do not know for sure but it should be (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(0) = 1$.

**Step 1.** $f$ is differentiable everywhere and satisfies $f'(x) = f(x)$. This is because

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f(x)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h) - 1}{h} = f(x)\lim_{h\to0}g(h) = f(x). $$

**Step 2.** $f(x) = e^x$. This follows from the observation that

$$ \left(f(x)e^{-x}\right)' = f'(x)e^{-x} - f(x)e^{-x} = 0. $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** What's another way of writing the derivative of $f$ at an arbitrary point $x$? Once you rewrite it, you should use the functional equations given to you to simplify.

**Hint 2:** What other function(s) do you know that satisfies the differential equation you created?

**Hint 3:** Can you find $f(0)$?

Comment: Sir,I have computed $f(0)=1$

Comment: Have you computed $f'(x)$ for arbitrary $x$?

Comment: Yes.I get $f'(x)=f(x)f'(0).$

Comment: Great. Then use what you found out about $f'(0)$ before and hint 2 to finish the problem

Comment: @user33640: You cannot easily say that $f$ is not zero at $x=0$ just by using that relation, however, it will be achieved later. Unless, you assume the function is not zero at all. In fact, I don't know what is $g(0)$ or even don't know that if this function is continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @user33640: I think, if we assume $f(0)=0$ then we don't have even 3.  It is enough to consider a non constant polynomial and so all options are vanished which we don't expect that, so $f$ is 1 as you got before. ;-)

Comment: @user33640 Hint to show that $f(0)\neq 0$: $f(x)$ is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and we know $f(x) = 1 + xg(x)$. Then $g$ must also be defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. You can use this equation to find $f(0)$ easily.

Comment: @BabakS.: By putting $x=0$ in $f(x)=1+xg(x)$ I get $f(0)=1$. Moreover OP says to have computed this as well. So I don't see why one should worry about the (im)possibility $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: Yes, you are right. I was just misunderstanding about that limit. Yes you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly eliminated options $2$ and $4$. To eliminate $3$, compare degrees in $f(2x)=f(x)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its $e^x.$

$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ $\implies$ This is a power function. Therefore answer has to be either $2^x$ or $e^x.$

Let $f(x)= 2^x$

$2^x=1+xg(x)$

$g(x)= \frac{2^x-1}{x}$

We have

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2^x-1}{x}= \log2$$ which is not equal to one.

Whereas,

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{e^x-1}{x}= 1$$

Comment: There is a function, assuming AC, that satisfies $f(x+y) =f(x)f(y)$ while failing to be a power function. But in view of the differentiability at $x = 0$, it must reduce to a power function.

Comment: Well, according to the condition of the problem . We can consider as a power function.